# Define a plane with double integral

Tags: calculus, physics

For my transport physics I have to describe how much volume through a rectangular pipe goes.
The speed is given by $\displaystyle V_x=V_0 \frac{y}{h}$.

But I have to define the plane with a double integral. 
[image: Situation]

I have to solve the equation on the right bottom hand of my picture. Which borders to I have to set and over which value $(dx, dy, dz)$ should I integrate.

I now that I can describe the plane by using pythagoras and the average speeds but I have to describe it with a double integral. 
Anyone an idea?

Kind regards,

Glenn